# Get innerText from div to input javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy each username one by one from a div with the same class name into an input field.

I got it where it will copy all text from div to input on button click but how can I separate usernames?

copy names one by one to the input so if i press the button it copy name 1 to input and if i press button again it copy name 2 to input but removes name 1 and if press again it copy name 3 to input and removes name 2

how can i split so it just copy one user name to input?

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("leaders");
var counter = elems.length;

function getUsers() {
  var Elem;
  if (counter <= 0)
    counter = elems.length;
  Elem = elems[counter - 1];
  document.getElementById("inp").value = Elem.innerText.split(" — ")[0].split(", ");
  counter--;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="leaders">user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4 — <strong>1</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 5, user 6, user 7, user 8 — <strong>2</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 9, user 10, user 11, user 12 — <strong>3</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 13, user 14, user 15, user 16 — <strong>4</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 17, user 18, user 19, user 20 — <strong>5</strong></div>
</div>
<br>


<input type="text" id="inp" style="width: 40%;"> &nbsp;
<button style="width: 40%;" onclick="getUsers();">copy user name to input</button>
```

Comment: What is your desired output please?

Comment: _but how can i separated usernames?_ What do you mean by that? Describe what you want to happen in more detail.

Comment: i want to copy username 1 to input on button click and if button clicked again copy the next username to the input but remove the username that is in the input be for next copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("leaders");
var counter = elems.length;
var arrayLength=0;
var maxLengthArray=0;

function getUsers() {
  var Elem;
  if (counter <= 0)
    counter = elems.length;
  Elem = elems[counter - 1];
  document.getElementById("inp").value = Elem.innerText.split(" — ")[0].split(", ")[arrayLength];
  maxLengthArray=Elem.innerText.split(" — ")[0].split(", ").length;
 if(maxLengthArray==arrayLength){
    arrayLength=0;
    counter--;
 }else{
    arrayLength++;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="leaders">user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4 — <strong>1</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 5, user 6, user 7, user 8 — <strong>2</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 9, user 10, user 11, user 12 — <strong>3</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 13, user 14, user 15, user 16 — <strong>4</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 17, user 18, user 19, user 20 — <strong>5</strong></div>
</div>
<br>


<input type="text" id="inp" style="width: 40%;"> &nbsp;
<button style="width: 40%;" onclick="getUsers();">copy user name to input</button>
```

I hope this is the expected result for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getUsers() {
//to remove strong tags
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i != len; ++i) {
    nodes[0].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[0]);
}

  var nameArray = "";
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("leaders");
  if (elems) {
    for (x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
      var res = elems[x].innerText;
      nameArray = res.split(",");
      inp.value += nameArray;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="leaders">user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4 — <strong>1</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 5, user 6, user 7, user 8 — <strong>2</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 9, user 10, user 11, user 12 — <strong>3</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 13, user 14, user 15, user 16 — <strong>4</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 17, user 18, user 19, user 20 — <strong>5</strong></div>
</div>
<br>


<input type="text" id="inp" style="width: 40%;">
&nbsp;
<button style="width: 40%;" onclick="getUsers();">copy user name to input</button>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it would be better if you provide an explanation and point out the problem with OP code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the users and add them to a separated array using `split()` then merge them using `concat()` when you want with the delimiter you want :

```js
function getUsers() {
  var users = [];
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("leaders");

  if (el.length) {
    for (x = 0; x < el.length - 1; x++) {
      users = users.concat(el[x].innerText.split(" — ")[0].split(", "))
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("inp").value = users.join(' - ');

  console.log(users);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" style="width: 100%;"> &nbsp;
<button onclick="getUsers();">copy user name to input</button>
<br>
<div class="user-list">
  <div class="leaders">user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4 — <strong>1</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 5, user 6, user 7, user 8 — <strong>2</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 9, user 10, user 11, user 12 — <strong>3</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 13, user 14, user 15, user 16 — <strong>4</strong></div>
  <div class="leaders">user 17, user 18, user 19, user 20 — <strong>5</strong></div>
</div>
```